# Как создать новые объекты через данные полученые из axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Добрый день всем.Нужно получить из данных, которые приходят через axios, новые объекты вида `{ ru: 1000, en: 2000 }` У меня сейчас есть такой запрос

```
componentDidMount(){
  axios.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
.then(response => {
      this.setState({

      countriesData:response.data,


  })
})
.catch((error) => {
      console.log("error", error)
})
```

}

Приходят данные в виде массива, как из них получить новые объекты для дальнейшего использования?

Comment: посмотрите lodash.zipObject

Comment: То есть приходит массив ... нужно сформировать объект ... что за магические ru/en? что за магические 1000/2000? Можете описать более подробно, а то суть проблемы вообще не ясна. Но да, лодаш поможет в любой непонятной ситуации ...